# Reputation audit does not match reputation on site

Tags: support, reputation

My current reputation audit at Super User (`/reputation`) displays, as of this writing, a reputation of 10825, but the reputation shown on the site is 10775, a discrepancy of 50 points.

Can someone look into this error, explain why it occurred, and recalculate my reputation score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A moderator removed "community wiki" from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/3227/does-windows-readyboost-have-a-meaningful-impact-on-performance/507520#507520). You're therefore due 50 reputation from the votes on it.

I triggered a recalc, so you should be all set.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233944/reputation-does-not-update-after-community-wiki-is-removed-from-a-post